# Print page issue in landscape and portrait view

Tags: html, css, angular

I have created a common component, across the application, to print the table. The table consists of multiple rows and columns. When the data is any cell is huge, each row is taking one complete page and the next row is getting printed on the next page. Due to this issue, empty space is getting created between the rows. I tried altering the column widths to get the look and feel but didn't help. So request your help providing a solution to print the table data without spaces issue.
Below is my code

```css
th {
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 5px; 
}
td {
    border: 1px solid  #e2e2e2;
    word-break: break-word;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: pre-wrap; 
}
.printPag {
    font-family: "calibri" !important;
    margin: 0.5cm 2cm;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
table
 {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 8pt;
}
```

```html
 Below is my code

    <table class="printPageTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let header of labels">
        {{ header.labels }}
      </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of tableData">
    <td *ngIf="data.tableDataCol_1 != undefined">
        <p *ngFor="let columnData of data.tableDataCol_1">
          {{ columnData }}
        </p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PLGL.png)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're after for a result but it sounds like you want to utilize the [@media print](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Paged_Media) media query with `page-break-after: avoid` set on your rows. You might check out [an article](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-handle-page-breaks-when-printing-a-large-html-table.html) or two and [some docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after) on how to address your concerns since we aren't provided a reproducible example of the current and desired result.

Comment: Agree with Chris W 
the at-media print query will allow you to customize your page for printing without affecting your standard web view.